# How to query a Sum using an array with duplicate data?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I currently have an Array in PHP with product numbers. Lets call that `products`.
In my database I have a table containing combinations of product numbers and the price that belongs to that product.

Problem: My Array can hold duplicate entries if for instance article #1 is ordered twice.

If I use a query like

```
SELECT SUM(price) FROM articles WHERE article_number IN (products)
```

the duplicate entry of 1 get discarded. The query I am looking for gives the sum of `10 + 10 + 12.5 + 9.95`.

Is there a way to do this within MySQL?

As a clarification to my data:

```
products = [1, 1, 2, 3];

articles|  article_number | price
__________________________________
        |  1              |  10.0
        |  2              |  12.5
        |  3              |  9.95
```

Thank you :)

Comment: You can use array unique function if you have issue with duplications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought there might be an easier way of doing this in SQL. I solved it in PHP by querying all the prices of the array's products and then in iterating over my Array in PHP to sum up the price there.

Answer (score 2):

winmutt has a solid answer.  However, if you don't have such a table to to join with then you could build your query like so:

```
select sum (p) from (
  (select price as p from articles where article_number = 1)
  union all
  (select price as p from articles where article_number = 1)
  union all
  (select price as p from articles where article_number = 2)
  union all
  (select price as p from articles where article_number = 3)
) s
```

Answer (score 1):

If your products were in a table you could do a simple JOIN:

```
SELECT SUM(price) FROM articles JOIN products on article_number=product_number
```